# Docker airflow image syntax for different git branches

Tags: git, docker, airflow, docker-image, docker-build

I have a docker deploy.sh file which creates an airflow image successfully

```
docker build -t airflow --build-arg CACHEBUST="$(date '+%A %W %Y %X')" -t airflow:latest .
```

The above script creates an image by default in master/development branch in git but I want to create another docker airflow image for the test branch in git. I'd really appreciate if I can get some help with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you've cloned airflow repository and you're trying to create docker image locally.

You can checkout the relevant branch, build a new image and also update its corresponding tag.

```
git checkout test

docker build -t airflow:test --build-arg CACHEBUST="$(date '+%A %W %Y %X')" .
```

`airflow:latest` will have the image from the master branch and `airflow:test` will have the image from the test branch.